# Tailwinds Box-shadow

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want a box shadow effect to look like this picture >>
[image]

Currently mine looks like this, How do i made the color darker and have it on all sides. [image]

```
 <div className="card shadow-xl shadow-gray-900">
```

This is my current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to do `shadow` at the center of the `div` with `tailwind`'s choices so you have to make a `custom shadow` yourself which is possible in `tailwind` like this:

```
<div class="bg-white drop-shadow-[0_0px_10px_rgba(0,0,0,0.25)] rounded-md">
        <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

or you can go to `tailwind.config.js` and add some custom CSS for example:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      dropShadow: {
        '3xl': '0 35px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)',
        '4xl': [
            '0 35px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)',
            '0 45px 65px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or another choice is to just make another CSS file (if you have already then no need to make another CSS file). and then add this:

```
.customShadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

then as for the `html` file:

```
<div class="bg-white customShadow rounded-md">
        <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```